# font awesome bag - not getting the right icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

hi I am trying to change my style of the icon from a star with empty space inside to full star
but I can't do in inside the before and after only

```
.survery-test label:after {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: fontAwesome;}
```

the problem is I can't change the style of the icon to a full star 
it's free on font awesome and I can't change it like inside the class.

**Solution:**

I used another [Fontawesome](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) CDN by bootstrap

Comment: Some styling requires a pro-plan (not free) so you could be coding it correctly but being inhibited externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the `content` of your class

```css
.survery-test label:after {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
}

.survery-test.empty label:after {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="survery-test">
  <label></label>
</div>

<div class="survery-test empty">
  <label></label>
</div>
```